# Failure to Create Descriptor or Sampler out of Depth Attachment on Vulkan

Tags: descriptor, vulkan, depth-buffer

In my project, I am trying to get the color and depth attachment information from the first render pass and use them in the second render pass as descriptor sets for other purposes. In order to do so, I created the vkDescriptorImageInfo and VkSampler objects of color and depth attachment respectively to hold their information. However, the color sampler and descriptor image info were successfully created in the pipeline, while the depth one were not since nothing could be read in the second pass. I attached my code below, including the definition of the first render pass (opaqueObjectPass) and the function that creates the render pass.

```
struct OpaqueObjectsPass
{
    int32_t width, height;
    VkFramebuffer frameBuffer;
    FrameBufferAttachment color, depth;
    VkRenderPass renderPass;
    VkSampler ColorSampler, DepthSampler;
    VkDescriptorImageInfo ColorDescriptor, DepthDescriptor;
    VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer = VK_NULL_HANDLE;

    VkSemaphore semaphore = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
} opaqueObjectPass;



void PrepareOpaqueRendering() 
{
    opaqueObjectPass.width = width;
    opaqueObjectPass.height = height;

    // find a suitable depth format
    VkFormat fbDepthFormat;
    VkBool32 validDepthFormat = vks::tools::getSupportedDepthFormat(physicalDevice, &fbDepthFormat);

    // color attachment
    VkImageCreateInfo l_Image = vks::initializers::imageCreateInfo();
    l_Image.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
    l_Image.format = FB_COLOR_FORMAT;
    l_Image.extent.width = opaqueObjectPass.width;
    l_Image.extent.height = opaqueObjectPass.height;
    l_Image.extent.depth = 1;
    l_Image.mipLevels = 1;
    l_Image.arrayLayers = 1;
    l_Image.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    l_Image.tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL;
    // We will sample directly from the color attachment
    l_Image.usage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT;

    VkMemoryAllocateInfo l_MemAlloc = vks::initializers::memoryAllocateInfo();
    VkMemoryRequirements l_MemReqs;

    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkCreateImage(device, &l_Image, nullptr, &opaqueObjectPass.color.image));
    vkGetImageMemoryRequirements(device, opaqueObjectPass.color.image, &l_MemReqs);
    l_MemAlloc.allocationSize = l_MemReqs.size;
    l_MemAlloc.memoryTypeIndex = vulkanDevice->getMemoryType(l_MemReqs.memoryTypeBits, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT);
    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkAllocateMemory(device, &l_MemAlloc, nullptr, &opaqueObjectPass.color.mem));
    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkBindImageMemory(device, opaqueObjectPass.color.image, opaqueObjectPass.color.mem, 0));

    VkImageViewCreateInfo l_ColorImageView = vks::initializers::imageViewCreateInfo();
    l_ColorImageView.viewType = VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D;
    l_ColorImageView.format = FB_COLOR_FORMAT;
    l_ColorImageView.subresourceRange = {};
    l_ColorImageView.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    l_ColorImageView.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
    l_ColorImageView.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
    l_ColorImageView.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    l_ColorImageView.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;
    l_ColorImageView.image = opaqueObjectPass.color.image;
    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkCreateImageView(device, &l_ColorImageView, nullptr, &opaqueObjectPass.color.view));

    // Create sampler to sample from the attachment in the fragment shader
    VkSamplerCreateInfo l_SamplerInfo = vks::initializers::samplerCreateInfo();
    l_SamplerInfo.magFilter = VK_FILTER_LINEAR;
    l_SamplerInfo.minFilter = VK_FILTER_LINEAR;
    l_SamplerInfo.mipmapMode = VK_SAMPLER_MIPMAP_MODE_LINEAR;
    l_SamplerInfo.addressModeU = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_CLAMP_TO_EDGE;
    l_SamplerInfo.addressModeV = l_SamplerInfo.addressModeU;
    l_SamplerInfo.addressModeW = l_SamplerInfo.addressModeU;
    l_SamplerInfo.mipLodBias = 0.0f;
    l_SamplerInfo.maxAnisotropy = 0;
    l_SamplerInfo.minLod = 0.0f;
    l_SamplerInfo.maxLod = 1.0f;
    l_SamplerInfo.borderColor = VK_BORDER_COLOR_FLOAT_OPAQUE_WHITE;
    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkCreateSampler(device, &l_SamplerInfo, nullptr, &opaqueObjectPass.ColorSampler));

    // Depth stencil attachment
    l_Image.format = fbDepthFormat;
    l_Image.usage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_BIT;
    //l_Image.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;

    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkCreateImage(device, &l_Image, nullptr, &opaqueObjectPass.depth.image));
    vkGetImageMemoryRequirements(device, opaqueObjectPass.depth.image, &l_MemReqs);
    l_MemAlloc.allocationSize = l_MemReqs.size;
    l_MemAlloc.memoryTypeIndex = vulkanDevice->getMemoryType(l_MemReqs.memoryTypeBits, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT);
    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkAllocateMemory(device, &l_MemAlloc, nullptr, &opaqueObjectPass.depth.mem));
    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkBindImageMemory(device, opaqueObjectPass.depth.image, opaqueObjectPass.depth.mem, 0));

    VkImageViewCreateInfo l_DepthStencilView = vks::initializers::imageViewCreateInfo();
    l_DepthStencilView.viewType = VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D;
    l_DepthStencilView.format = fbDepthFormat;
    l_DepthStencilView.flags = 0;
    l_DepthStencilView.subresourceRange = {};
    l_DepthStencilView.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_DEPTH_BIT | VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_STENCIL_BIT;
    l_DepthStencilView.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
    l_DepthStencilView.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
    l_DepthStencilView.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    l_DepthStencilView.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;
    l_DepthStencilView.image = opaqueObjectPass.depth.image;
    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkCreateImageView(device, &l_DepthStencilView, nullptr, &opaqueObjectPass.depth.view));

    // create a sampler of depth buffer
    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkCreateSampler(device, &l_SamplerInfo, nullptr, &opaqueObjectPass.DepthSampler));

    // Create a separate render pass for the offscreen rendering as it may differ from the one used for scene rendering

    std::array<VkAttachmentDescription, 2> l_AttchmentDescriptions = {};
    // Color attachment
    l_AttchmentDescriptions[0].format = FB_COLOR_FORMAT;
    l_AttchmentDescriptions[0].samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    l_AttchmentDescriptions[0].loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
    l_AttchmentDescriptions[0].storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
    l_AttchmentDescriptions[0].stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
    l_AttchmentDescriptions[0].stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    l_AttchmentDescriptions[0].initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    l_AttchmentDescriptions[0].finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;
    // Depth attachment
    l_AttchmentDescriptions[1].format = fbDepthFormat;
    l_AttchmentDescriptions[1].samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    l_AttchmentDescriptions[1].loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_LOAD;
    l_AttchmentDescriptions[1].storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
    l_AttchmentDescriptions[1].stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_LOAD;
    l_AttchmentDescriptions[1].stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
    l_AttchmentDescriptions[1].initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    l_AttchmentDescriptions[1].finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

    VkAttachmentReference l_ColorReference = { 0, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL };
    VkAttachmentReference l_DepthReference = { 1, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL };

    VkSubpassDescription subpassDescription = {};
    subpassDescription.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
    subpassDescription.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
    subpassDescription.pColorAttachments = &l_ColorReference;
    subpassDescription.pDepthStencilAttachment = &l_DepthReference;

    // Use subpass dependencies for layout transitions
    std::array<VkSubpassDependency, 2> l_Dependencies;

    l_Dependencies[0].srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
    l_Dependencies[0].dstSubpass = 0;
    l_Dependencies[0].srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT;
    l_Dependencies[0].dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
    l_Dependencies[0].srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT;
    l_Dependencies[0].dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
    l_Dependencies[0].dependencyFlags = VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT;

    l_Dependencies[1].srcSubpass = 0;
    l_Dependencies[1].dstSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
    l_Dependencies[1].srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
    l_Dependencies[1].dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT;
    l_Dependencies[1].srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
    l_Dependencies[1].dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT;
    l_Dependencies[1].dependencyFlags = VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT;

    // Create the actual renderpass
    VkRenderPassCreateInfo l_RenderPassInfo = {};
    l_RenderPassInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_CREATE_INFO;
    l_RenderPassInfo.attachmentCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(l_AttchmentDescriptions.size());
    l_RenderPassInfo.pAttachments = l_AttchmentDescriptions.data();
    l_RenderPassInfo.subpassCount = 1;
    l_RenderPassInfo.pSubpasses = &subpassDescription;
    l_RenderPassInfo.dependencyCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(l_Dependencies.size());
    l_RenderPassInfo.pDependencies = l_Dependencies.data();

    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkCreateRenderPass(device, &l_RenderPassInfo, nullptr, &opaqueObjectPass.renderPass));

    VkImageView l_Attachments[2];
    l_Attachments[0] = opaqueObjectPass.color.view;
    l_Attachments[1] = opaqueObjectPass.depth.view;

    VkFramebufferCreateInfo l_fbufCreateInfo = vks::initializers::framebufferCreateInfo();
    l_fbufCreateInfo.renderPass = opaqueObjectPass.renderPass;
    l_fbufCreateInfo.attachmentCount = 2;
    l_fbufCreateInfo.pAttachments = l_Attachments;
    l_fbufCreateInfo.width = opaqueObjectPass.width;
    l_fbufCreateInfo.height = opaqueObjectPass.height;
    l_fbufCreateInfo.layers = 1;

    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkCreateFramebuffer(device, &l_fbufCreateInfo, nullptr, &opaqueObjectPass.frameBuffer));

    // Fill a descriptor for later use in a descriptor set 
    opaqueObjectPass.ColorDescriptor.imageLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;
    opaqueObjectPass.ColorDescriptor.imageView = opaqueObjectPass.color.view;
    opaqueObjectPass.ColorDescriptor.sampler = opaqueObjectPass.ColorSampler;

    opaqueObjectPass.DepthDescriptor.imageLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;
    opaqueObjectPass.DepthDescriptor.imageView = opaqueObjectPass.depth.view;
    opaqueObjectPass.DepthDescriptor.sampler = opaqueObjectPass.DepthSampler;
}


void PrepareOpaquePipeline() 
{
    VkPipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo l_InputAssemblyState =
        vks::initializers::pipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo(VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLE_LIST, 0, VK_FALSE);

    VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo l_RasterizationState =
        vks::initializers::pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo(VK_POLYGON_MODE_FILL, VK_CULL_MODE_FRONT_BIT, VK_FRONT_FACE_CLOCKWISE, 0);

    VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState l_BlendAttachmentState =
        vks::initializers::pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState(0xf, VK_FALSE);

    VkPipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo l_ColorBlendState =
        vks::initializers::pipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo(1, &l_BlendAttachmentState);

    VkPipelineDepthStencilStateCreateInfo l_DepthStencilState =
        vks::initializers::pipelineDepthStencilStateCreateInfo(VK_TRUE, VK_TRUE, VK_COMPARE_OP_LESS_OR_EQUAL);

    VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo l_ViewportState =
        vks::initializers::pipelineViewportStateCreateInfo(1, 1, 0);

    VkPipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo l_MultisampleState =
        vks::initializers::pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo(VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT, 0);

    std::vector<VkDynamicState> l_DynamicStateEnables = {VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_VIEWPORT, VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_SCISSOR};
    VkPipelineDynamicStateCreateInfo l_DynamicState =
        vks::initializers::pipelineDynamicStateCreateInfo(l_DynamicStateEnables.data(), l_DynamicStateEnables.size(), 0);

    // Solid rendering pipeline
    // Load shaders
    std::array<VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo, 2> l_ShaderStages;

    l_ShaderStages[0] = loadShader(getAssetPath() + "shaders/offscreen/opaque.vert.spv", VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT);
    l_ShaderStages[1] = loadShader(getAssetPath() + "shaders/offscreen/opaque.frag.spv", VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT);

    VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo l_PipelineCreateInfo =
        vks::initializers::pipelineCreateInfo(pipelineLayouts.opaque, opaqueObjectPass.renderPass, 0);

    l_PipelineCreateInfo.pVertexInputState = &vertices.inputState;
    l_PipelineCreateInfo.pInputAssemblyState = &l_InputAssemblyState;
    l_PipelineCreateInfo.pRasterizationState = &l_RasterizationState;
    l_PipelineCreateInfo.pColorBlendState = &l_ColorBlendState;
    l_PipelineCreateInfo.pMultisampleState = &l_MultisampleState;
    l_PipelineCreateInfo.pViewportState = &l_ViewportState;
    l_PipelineCreateInfo.pDepthStencilState = &l_DepthStencilState;
    l_PipelineCreateInfo.pDynamicState = &l_DynamicState;
    l_PipelineCreateInfo.stageCount = l_ShaderStages.size();
    l_PipelineCreateInfo.pStages = l_ShaderStages.data();

    // create graphics pipeline of opaque
    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkCreateGraphicsPipelines(device, pipelineCache, 1, &l_PipelineCreateInfo, nullptr, &pipelines.opaque));

}
```

Probably I set couples of property flags improperly and I appreciate any suggestions for the correct property setting and to make the descriptor set working in the second render pass.

Comment: I don't see where you change the layouts for the images that you're trying to read from.

Comment: The layout of color image is VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL, while the depth image is set as VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL. They are at the end of function PrepareOpaqueRendering(). But I am not sure if you are asking about these image layout changes. Thanks.

Comment: I see that you *declare* that the images will be in those layouts when using them as descriptors. But I don't see where you *actually put them* into those layouts. Your final render pass layout puts the depth attachment in `DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL`.

Comment: I have changed the final layout and attachment reference to be VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL, the same as image layout in descriptors. However, it does not solve the problem.

Comment: _"successfully created in the pipeline, while the depth one were not since nothing could be read in the second pass"_

That sounds ambiguous. If the depth sampler (and descriptor) could not be created the validation layer would display an error about that.

From your use-case I think the problem is in the second pass where you try reading from the depth attachment you created in the first pass, so if you could pass the code of your second, depth-reading pass, we may be able to spot the problem.

Comment: I think the depth-reading process is done in the first pass and the read-back depth data is stored by the depth descriptor and used in the second render pass.

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems is in Your depth-image creation code. You set a valid usage flags for the color image (color attachment + sampled), but not for the depth image (only depth attachment):

```
// Depth stencil attachment
l_Image.format = fbDepthFormat;
l_Image.usage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_BIT;
```

This way You can only render depth data into the image but You can't read it. Add VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT flag to the usage and check if the problem still persists. If it is there is also another problem somewhere else.